How to check if two unix timestamps are included in five minutes by using DateTime Class
How to check in PHP if 2 unix timestamps are in a range on 5 minutes by using DateTime Class?
I'm refering to five minutes of clock, not (5*60 secs). When exactly the minute passes looking at the system clock.
So it could be for example a range from 04:59 to 05:04.
In this case if the timestamps are are referred to 04:59 and 05:04 for example it should be true.
I'm having a lot of trouble with the different days and hours, otherwise a simple subtraction would have been enough.
function checker($timestamp1, $timestamp2){
    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $date2 = new DateTime();
    $date1->setTimestamp($timestamp1);
    $date2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);
    $a_date = $date1->format('d m Y');
    $b_date = $date2->format('d m Y');

    // I'm lost exactly here
    // WHAT CODE I HAVE TO WRITE FROM HERE ON?!?!

    if ($a_date != $b_date) { return 0; } //WRONG CODE FOR "14 10 2024 00:00:10" AND "13 10 2024 23:59:00" 
    $a_hour = $date1->format('H');
    $b_hour = $date2->format('H');
    if (abs($a_hour - $b_hour) > 2) { return 0; }
    $a = $date1->getTimestamp();
    $b = $date2->getTimestamp();
    if (abs($a - $b) <= 5*60 ) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
}

N.B. For what I'm doing it's important that the function uses DateTime Class.
EDIT
After talking in comments with @C3roe and using https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php so subtracting the interval it's very difficult for me to move on.
function checker($timestamp1, $timestamp2){
    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $date2 = new DateTime();
    $date1->setTimestamp($timestamp1);
    $date2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    // WHAT TO DO HERE?!?!?!
    echo 'RESULT: '.$interval->format('%d.%m.%Y %H %i'); 
}

In the meantime, to help you understand better, I created a little demonstration.
https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/58tMVsphqDk1K

Use DateTime::diff, and then check on the properties of the resulting DateInterval.

//WRONG CODE FOR "14 10 2024 00:00:10" AND "13 10 2024 23:59:00"  - that's likely where the switch between summer and winder time happens in your timezone. Working with the difference between the actual unix timestamps doesn't work well when you're crossing this "boundary."

@C3roe if you wrote some code to understand better it would be much cooler  So write something good also to avoid the problem of solar time and daylight saving time. P.S. Unix timestamps are all the same for all timezone

P.P.S both timestamps refer to the same timezone. P.P.P.S. I hate summer I hate winter I hate the time that changes between solar time and daylight saving time I hate everything that destroys and makes the code wrong for "14 10 2024 00:00:10" AND "13 10 2024 23:59:00". Time in my opinion is the most difficult thing in the world.

How do you pass those timestamps to the function?  You can probably just work with them..

@Wimanicesir are unix timestamps that arrive at the function using the system timestamp (the first) and a generic timestamp (the second). Work with them, yes, but how?!

If they are unix timestamps, I don't get why you would set them and then get them to compare them then. Just compare them from the get go?
function checker($timestamp1, $timestamp2){
    if (abs($timestamp1 - $timestamp2) <= 5*60 ) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
}

EDIT:
If I understand you correctly you worry about the seconds, an example how I see your problem:
11:45:30 -> 11:50:31 is according to the seconds equal to more than 5 minutes
But according to the minutes (11:45 -> 11:50) it is not more.
If that is the case, we can solve this easily with some basic math:
Unix timestamps are in seconds so if we want to know exactly how many minutes are passed we can divide it by 60 and use a floor()
$minutes = floor($timestamp1 / 60)

If you do this for both, you compare the minutes and disregard the seconds.
If you want to convert it to dateTime, I would advise to do this inside another function. This function should just check whether it's more or less than 5 minutes difference.

TNX. Good. Yes, they are unix timestamps, but with this function you do not respect the exact minute. You only check the seconds. Not if the seconds correspond to the minute. I do not know if I explained myself well in the question.

Also I need to convert them by using DateTime to change them later (as the previous user said, I'm interested in solar time and daylight saving time). What I'm dealing with now is only the first part of the function, which in my opinion is the most complicated.

For daylight savings checking, I would advise you to do this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/daylight-saving-time-handling-in-php/

@ Wimanicesir I think you are good. Sometimes my brain goes mush. A simple floor of basic math (/60) to control the minutes and leave out the seconds!!! I want to bang my head against the wall. Ok, you have solved all the problems. Well done. answer +1. Top.
Anyway, I'm not stupid. I just made a fool of myself. P.S. I don't need to check the daylight saving time. Datetime already does that. I subtract and the result is already subtracted using solar time and daylight saving time. Thanks. You were great. Bye
